# Will using await on Task.Run casue "access to disposed closure" error?

Tags: c#, async-await, resharper

### Code Sample

```cs
public async Task HeavyTask()
{
  using(var res = new BigResource())
  {
    await Task.Run(() => service.Do(res));
  }
}
```

I have some code that looks like above, and ReSharper warns me about "Access to disposed closure" on the use of the `res` instance.

If I did not use the `await` keyword, I know the `res` instance *might* be disposed when the `service` tries to access it.

But I think if I use the `await` keyword, the thread that executes the `HeavyTask` method will not continue until the `Task.Run` is completed, and there should be no risk of accessing a disposed closure.

Please help me understand where I went wrong, and what would be the preferred pattern to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going wrong. This won't access `res` after it's disposed. The problem is simply that ReSharper doesn't know that. `Task.Run` *could* store the delegate in order to execute it later. The only way you know it doesn't do that is because you know what `Task.Run` does. ReSharper does not.

Comment: While I could understand Resharper’s behavior for every other function call, it not being special-cased to know what Task.Run does is kind of sad :/

Comment: @poke I agree, but would like to add that the BCL has a *lot* more methods that are used just as much of not more that should get the same special-casing.

Comment: This isn't related to Task.Run but rather to async method which is going to be used to generate totally different code (so called async state machine). So Resharper is not merely aware of result code.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov That's not true and you could easily have checked that by seeing if the warning is generated for variables that aren't captured by a lambda.

Comment: @hvd I'm not sure what exactly is not true ?

Comment: Do you guys think it is a bug in ReShaper, or it is a feature that is never gonna get implemented?

Comment: @davidshen84 Missing feature, but it might be implemented. ReSharper allows attributes to affect such warnings and supports an [`InstantHandleAttribute`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html) to indicate that the delegate will not be invoked after the method returns. That is not appropriate for `Task.Run`, but a similar attribute to indicate that the delegate will not be invoked after the returned task is marked as completed could be added, and when it is, ReSharper will surely implicitly annotate `Task.Run` with it.